# R Programming brew vs. Sweave-- suppressing output and brew limitations

Tags: r, sweave

I am a newbie to the R world-- a couple of weeks. I have been tasked to automate the generation of a database codebook. The thought was to use R, LaTex, and Sweave as a solution. Because of the repetitive nature of the codebook tables and the use of looping over code chunks, Sweave may not be a viable means. It looks like the brew package could be an alternative. As I have been doing some testing with brew, I'm running into an issue with loading in the RMySQL package (via library(RMySQL)) as I cannot suppress the output--

```
Looking in C:Files/MySQL, C:/MySQL, D:/MySQL, E:/MySQL, F:/MySQL,
G:/MySQL, C:/xampp/MySQL, D:/xampp/MySQL, E:/xampp/MySQL, F:/xampp/MySQL,
G:/xampp/MySQL, C:/Apps/MySQL, D:/Apps/MySQL, E:/Apps/MySQL, F:/Apps/MySQL,
G:/Apps/MySQL Found C:Files/MySQL
```

I have tried to set the Library function arguments verbose=TRUE and quietly=TRUE but that did not work. In Sweave, I am able to suppress by setting the code chunk option to results=hide. Is there any alternative to suppress this output information when using brew?

In determining whether or not brew is a good solution for the codebook generation, should I be aware of any limitations of brew as compared to Sweave?

Answer (score 2):

To supress messages during loading of a library:

```
suppressMessages(library(RMySQL))
```

Also, definitely take a look at the `knitr` package. It roughly does what Sweave does, but then better. It supports caching of objects (which kept me from heavily using Sweave), and much more flexibility. Take a look at the [website](http://yihui.name/knitr/), or on a [blogpost of mine](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2012/02/12/r-and-presentations-a-basic-example-of-knitr-and-beamer/) showing a simple example of a presentation in Latex made using knitr and beamer.

Comment: I'm still a Sweave user (and use the `cacheSweave` and `pgfSweave` packages when I need to cache objects). That said `knitr` looks appealing. Is it able to process existing Sweave documents without requiring any edits to them?

Comment: @Josh: I'm 95% confident it is compatible with your Sweave documents (see http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/; this page describes knitr 0.3 which is not on CRAN yet: https://github.com/yihui/knitr) @Paul: thanks, another way to do it is to set the chunk option `message=FALSE`

Comment: @Yihui -- Thanks. That all looks really impressive. I'll try out knitr as soon as I get a chance.